# To_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE('10-04-10','RR-MM-DD'), 'YY'), -1), 'Q')

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to break the statement part by part to understand but it seem having some error. Appreciate if someone can explain this to me.

Thanks

```
select To_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE('10-04-10','RR-MM-DD'), 'YY'), -1), 'Q')
from dual
```

Comment: Please explain the error.

Comment: Horrible title.  Please make the title something that briefly describes your issue.  What would you google if you were trying to find this question?

Comment: Start with `SELECT TO_DATE('10-04-10','RR-MM-DD') FROM DUAL` and keep adding one function at a time.

Comment: @rory.ap Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_DATE('10-04-10','RR-MM-DD')` creates a date data type with the value 10th April 2010.

`TRUNC( date_value, 'YY' )` truncates the date to midnight of the first day of the year. I.e. 1st January 2010 in this case.

`ADD_MONTHS( date_value, -1 )` adds `-1` months to the date. I.e. 1st December 2009.

`TO_CHAR( date_value, 'Q' )` outputs the quarter of the year. I.e. `4`